# Get logs for file transfer using any medium

Tags: applications, logging, superuser

Is there any app (using root permission also if possible) using which i can get logs for file transfer using MTP or Over Bluetooth.

I know about SysLog app but does it print MTP logs also.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? The answer might not be as simple as just installing an app.

Comment: I want to find some files are copied from my machine or not on particular day.